# Monitor won't display anything when turned on

Tags: display, gpu

It's been a month now since my computer started having problems when being turned on. 
What happens is, the monitor keeps switching from sleep mode to awake mode. 
While doing this, the screen gradually keeps getting darker and the GPU makes a small noise after every switch.

Then, 10-15 minutes later, the monitor finally turns on and output "HDMI Signal Detected".

Is my GPU or monitor dying?

---Edit---

I did update the drivers recently and It's a custom built desktop. 
I haven't upgraded anything in two years and the monitor is 6-7 years old. 
Also, i don't have two monitors so, i can't test whether the monitor is dying or not.

---Edit---

It was the monitor, my older graphic card ended up doing the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried another monitor??  If the same behavior occurs on the new monitor then your card is going out.

Comment: Desktop? Laptop? OS? Do you have Flux or any other monitor managing programs installed? What have you tried? Have you updated display drivers? Have you configured anything involving sleep mode? Have you tried using another monitor? another GPU?

Comment: @Wutnaut, I'd upvote you more for that, but I can't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Test the Monitor ==> Switch to a new monitor.

To Test the GPU ==> Download the Benchmarking Software recommended by your GPU manufacturer.  If the test Pass, switch to the VGA port if any.  If the issue clears, the HDMI port is faulty but the card is functioning.  If the tests fail, put the GPU in another system.  If problem clears, the voltage on your motherboard is at fault, but if the problem persists, the GPU is at fault.